# How to extract filename inside the folder based on pattern in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have four sample CSV files as below in folder

`1234_ABCD_XYZ_Sep 2018_20181130_09-00-18`

`TestingFile_20181025_CR_090819`

`FileSample20181130144037-11`

`SampleFile_20181025_AB_090819`

I need to extract the filename as below in Powershell

`ABCD_XYZ_Sep 2018`

`TestingFile_20181025`

`FileSample20181130`

`SampleFile_20181025_AB`

Comment: 1234_ABCD_XYZ_Sep 2018_20181130_09-00-18, TestingFile_20181025_CR_090819, FileSample20181130144037-11 and SampleFile_20181025_AB_090819 All of these are one file name?

Comment: No, Its four files which are in different pattern

Comment: As far as I recognise there's no common pattern. How do you distinguish the filenames from the rest of the strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a regex pattern for this where the filename parts are joined with the `OR` symbol `|`:

```
$re = 'ABCD_XYZ_Sep 2018|TestingFile_20181025_CR|FileSample20181130|SampleFile_20181025_AB'
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter *.csv -File | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match $re }).FullName
```

If you're on PowerShell version below 3.0, use this instead of the `-File` switch:

```
$re = 'ABCD_XYZ_Sep 2018|TestingFile_20181025_CR|FileSample20181130|SampleFile_20181025_AB'
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter *.csv | Where-Object { !$_.PsIsContainer -and $_.BaseName -match $re }).FullName
```

Output:

> ```
> D:\Test\1234_ABCD_XYZ_Sep 2018_20181130_09-00-18.csv
> D:\Test\FileSample20181130144037-11.csv
> D:\Test\SampleFile_20181025_AB_090819.csv
> D:\Test\TestingFile_20181025_CR_090819.csv
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Give an input parent folder path where these csv files are stored.
2. Create an array for all the patterns
3. For each pattern in patterns list loop through every item in the parent folder and compare if the name of each 'file' item matches the given pattern. (Check only files, not folders; However recurse is used to search any files within subfolders as well, if applicable)
   Keep adding the results for each pattern match to an arraylist variable 'filelist'

Below is the code,

```
# Sample Source Folder Path
$sourceFolderPath = "D:\CSVFilesFolder"

$patterns_array = @(
"ABCD_XYZ_Sep 2018",
"TestingFile_20181025_CR",
"FileSample20181130",
"SampleFile_20181025_AB"
)

$filelist = New-object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach($pattern in $patterns_array) { 
    $files = gci $sourceFolderPath -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Name -match "*$pattern*.csv" }
    $filelist.Add($files)
}

$filelist
```

Cheers!

~K

Comment: Thank you Karthick. I will try as you mentioned